# Pandas - Scalar operation of a Panda subset indexed by "loc"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello and thanks in advance for any tip or advice.

I have a Panda DataFrame "df"  that looks like this:

```
      Next Origin  values
A3-S  B3-M   A3-S       6
A3-S  D4-M   B3-M       7
D4-M  A4-M   D4-M       6
A4-M  A4-S   A4-M       6
```

I want to sum all the values in column "values" for all rows within a given label and then divide each value in "values" in the same rows by the sum obtained  - So values are normalized between 0 and 1 for that label rows.

With: 
`sum = dataf.loc['A3-S','values'].sum()` I have the sum of values in column "values" for the label "A3-S", like:

```
A3-S    6
A3-S    3
A3-S    1
A3-S    1
A3-S    1
A3-S    2
Total : 14
```

When I try to divide each row of the block I am interested in, by the sum

```
dataf.loc['A3-S', 'values']= dataf.loc['A3-S','values'] / sum
```

I get error:

```
in _setitem_with_indexer
    raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I have tried with other options with no success like:

```
dataf.loc['A3-S', 'values'] = dataf.loc['A3-S', 'values'].apply(lambda x: x/sumat)
```

Any idea of how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [23]: df['val_norm'] = df.groupby(level=0)['values'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
      Next Origin  values  val_norm
A3-S  B3-M   A3-S       6  0.461538
A3-S  D4-M   B3-M       7  0.538462
D4-M  A4-M   D4-M       6  1.000000
A4-M  A4-S   A4-M       6  1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you MaxU, it is working for me. I am trying to understand the options and possibilities under "groupby" on the documentation.